# VBS Error - Permission Denied while deleting files

Tags: vbscript

I am writing a simple script to delete all text files from "My Documents" directory. The script is working fine but after deleting the last file, it gives Permission Denied (Error Code: 800A0046). For example, if I have 3 .txt files in the directory, the error occurs after the 3rd file is deleted.
I don't think it's a permission issue because in that case, no file would have been deleted. It's something very basic that I am missing. I have added a 1-second delay, which allows me to see the files getting deleted one after another.
Here is the script:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

objFolder = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").specialfolders("MyDocuments")

Dim objFile

For each objFile in objFolder.Files
If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "txt" Then
objFSO.DeleteFile(objFile), True
Wscript.Sleep 1000
End If
Next
```

Comment: And the "Permission Denied" error occurs on which line in this script? Because `800A0046` is not the error you would get for an access denied situation on the file system. My suspicion is either that your sample here and your actual script are different and the error occurs on some line you're not showing, or maybe that the error is somewhere in the code that calls this script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change this line to set the ***objFolder*** :

`objFolder = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").specialfolders("MyDocuments")`

to

`Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments"))`

And here is a quick test to list all my text files in My Documents folder :

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO,objFile,objFolder,MyDoc,F
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
MyDoc = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")

Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(MyDoc)

For each objFile in objFolder.Files
If LCase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = "txt" Then
    F = F & objFile & vbcrlf
End If
Next
wscript.echo F
```

Comment: Excellent answer.